# Javers returns incomplete diff when entity field type is changed (inheritance)

Tags: javers

Javers returns incomplete diff when a field of an entity is declared using an abstract type.

I am using Javers 2.9.2, but also tried 5.4.0. My issue appeared in both versions.

I have a model like the following:

```java
// An entity.
class Entity {

  AbstractType field;
}

abstract class AbstractType {}

// A value object.
class ConcreteA extends AbstractType {

  AnotherEntity entityA;
}

// A value object.
class ConcreteB extends AbstractType {

  AnotherEntity entityB;

  // Other fields are omitted for simplicity.
}

// The class registered as an entity.
class AnotherEntity {

  String uuid;
  String name;
}
```

I am registering the entities and value objects above.

Comparing the following objects:

```java
AnotherEntity anotherEntity = new AnotherEntity("name");

Entity originalEntity = new Entity();
originalEntity.field = new ConcreteA(anotherEntity);

Entity updatedEntity = new Entity();
updatedEntity.field = new ConcreteB(anotherEntity);

javers.compare(originalEntity, updatedEntity);
```

I expect the diff saying that:

- Field `entityA` was removed.
- Field `entityB` was added.

But instead, the diff says that only field `entityA` was removed (`ReferenceChange`). So, one field is missing in the diff.

How can I get the complete diff for my case?

Comment: And what is AnotherEntity?

Comment: @BartekWalacik I have added the declaration of `AnotherEntity`. The principal moment is that it is an entity, not a value object. To reproduce the issue it can be any entity.

Comment: This code wont compile, constructors are undefined, try to push runnable test case here https://github.com/javers/javers/tree/master/javers-core/src/test/groovy/org/javers/core/cases

Comment: @BartekWalacik Here is the [test case](https://github.com/kamaek/javers/commit/48dd0613c352fc8ae7520b435e8fb0f40ef719c5). The test fails in 5.4.0.

Occasionally I spotted that in 5.5.0 the test passes. So, seems my issue is solved. Let's merge the test case if there is no similar one to avoid any regression.

Comment: Ok, I will check if your case is covered in the current test suite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 5.5.0 we have added better support for types refactoring. Added/removed properties are detected and Javers calculates correct diff for them.
Each `PropertyChange` has the new enum — `PropertyChangeType` indicating if a property is added/removed:

```java
/**
 * When two objects being compared have different classes,
 * they can have different sets of properties.
 * <br/>
 * When both objects have the same class, all changes have PROPERTY_VALUE_CHANGED type.
 *
 * @since 5.5.0
 */
public enum PropertyChangeType {

    /**
     * When a property of the right object is absent in the left object.
     */
    PROPERTY_ADDED,

    /**
     * When a property of the left object is absent in the right object.
     */
    PROPERTY_REMOVED,

    /**
     * Regular value change &mdash; when a property is present in both objects.
     */
    PROPERTY_VALUE_CHANGED
}
```

`PropertyChangeType` is also reflected in `diff.prettyPrint()`:

```java
Diff diff = javers.compare(originalEntity, updatedEntity)

println diff.prettyPrint()
```

```
Diff:
* changes on org.javers.core.cases.Entity/123 :
  - 'field.entityA' property with reference '...AnotherEntity/uuid' removed
  - 'field.entityB' property with reference '...AnotherEntity/uuid' added
```